# How do I cast Char into correct format (as.POSIXct) I believe

Tags: r, casting, posixct

Thanks for the help. I am new to coding and having trouble with casting char to as.POSIXct.
##MYCode

```
bike_rides$month <- format(as.Date(bike_rides$date), "%m")
bike_rides$day <- format(as.Date(bike_rides$date), "%d")
bike_rides$year <- format(as.Date(bike_rides$date), "%y")
bike_rides$weekday <- format(as.Date(bike_rides$date), "%a")
bike_rides$start_hour = format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$started_at), "%H")
bike_rides$end_hour = format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$ended_at), "%H")
bike_rides$season <- ifelse (bike_rides$month %in% c('06','07','08'), "Summer",
                         ifelse (bike_rides$month %in% c('09','10','11'), "Fall",
                                 ifelse (bike_rides$month %in% c('12','01','02'), "Winter",
                                         ifelse (bike_rides$month %in% c('03','04','05'), "Spring", NA))))
```

Error from Kaggle

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Traceback:
format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$started_at), "%H")
as.POSIXct(bike_rides$started_at)
as.POSIXct.default(bike_rides$started_at)
as.POSIXct(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...)
as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...)
as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...)
stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
```

##Dput for my DF

```
    bike_rides <-
  structure(
    list(
      ride_id = c("A847FADBBC638E45", "5405B80E996FF60D",
                  "5DD24A79A4E006F4"),
      rideable_type = c("docked_bike", "docked_bike",
                        "docked_bike"),
      started_at = structure(
        c(1587923114, 1587143334,
          1585763653),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = "UTC"
      ),
      ended_at = structure(
        c(1587924723, 1587143823, 1585764516),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = "UTC"
      ),
      start_station_name = c("Eckhart Park",
                             "Drake Ave & Fullerton Ave", "McClurg Ct & Erie St"),
      start_station_id = c("86",
                           "503", "142"),
      end_station_name = c(
        "Lincoln Ave & Diversey Pkwy",
        "Kosciuszko Park",
        "Indiana Ave & Roosevelt Rd"
      ),
      end_station_id = c("152",
                         "499", "255"),
      start_lat = c(41.8964, 41.9244, 41.8945),
      start_lng = c(-87.661,-87.7154,-87.6179),
      end_lat = c(41.9322,
                  41.9306, 41.8679),
      end_lng = c(-87.6586,-87.7238,-87.623),
      member_casual = c("member", "member", "member"),
      date = structure(c(18378,
                         18369, 18353), class = "Date"),
      month = c("04", "04", "04"),
      day = c("26", "17", "01"),
      year = c("20", "20", "20"),
      weekday = c("Sun", "Fri", "Wed"),
      start_hour = c("17", "17",
                     "17"),
      end_hour = c("18", "17", "18"),
      season = c("Spring",
                 "Spring", "Spring")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 3L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

I have been looking everywhere but somehow in the stack of code below;

```
    bike_rides$start_hour = format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$started_at), "%H")
bike_rides$end_hour = format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$ended_at), "%H")
```

Does not work and I can not figure a better way or syntax to make that argument run.

Comment: From your `dput` output, `started_at` is already of class `POSIXt`, why are you trying to reconvert it? BTW, I cannot reproduce an error with any of the data or code you have here.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate) 

df %>%
  mutate(
    month = month(date),
    day = day(date),
    year = year(date),
    weekday = weekdays(date),
    season = quarter(date),
    start_hour = hour(started_at),
    end_hour = hour(ended_at)) %>% 
  select(ride_id, date, month, day, year, weekday, season, start_hour, end_hour)
    
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  ride_id          date       month   day  year weekday   season start_hour end_hour
  <chr>            <date>     <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>      <int>      <int>    <int>
1 A847FADBBC638E45 2020-04-26     4    26  2020 Sunday         2         17       18
2 5405B80E996FF60D 2020-04-17     4    17  2020 Friday         2         17       17
3 5DD24A79A4E006F4 2020-04-01     4     1  2020 Wednesday      2         17       18
```

Comment: this is the error iI get when I replace the code. FYI i was running lubridate. Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `start_hour = hour(started_at)`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @JamarWilson could you share the original dataset? Curious about that date format.

Comment: I am sorry can you please inform me what do you mean. I am so new and a bit overwhelmed been stuck with this issue for 5 days. By sharing my dataset do you mean sharing my code? or are you referring to Dput?  If you are referring to Dput is used dput(bike_rides[1:3,]) to get first 3 rows. What would I do to get the whole dataset if thats what you want? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JamarWilson yes, your 3 first rows of the data you want to transform would be nice!

Comment: I am sorry I still do not quite understand. From my understanding I sent the first 3 rows in dput of my data frame. I also sent the code chunk of what is not working. To be exact bike_rides$start_hour = format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$started_at), "%H")
bike_rides$end_hour = format(as.POSIXct(bike_rides$ended_at), "%H") is what is bringing me the error. Everything else works perfectly fine. I do not know how to create a column for start_hour and end_hour casting the column to read the %H=hour without getting a error. Everything else in that code chunk works perfectly fine.

Comment: @JamarWilson I created the columns with `hour()` that is working for me though. Is your date column in date format already or is it in character?

Comment: it is in char. the only column that is in cast date is the date column. start_lat,start_lng, end_lat, end_lng are num and every other column is chr. @tomhoel